# How to have the event handler be called just once and not being recursively called in Grid View

Tags: asp.net

I have a check box in a Grid View. It has many columns. In the grid view there are two columns namely PO AND PT. If I check PO check box, I want to check all check boxes of the same column and also all the check boxes of PT column.

This is what I implemented. But I doubt this will cause recursive function. How can I stop this. The following is my code.

```
    Protected Sub chkPO_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim CheckPerOblig As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
       EnableDisableAllPOPT(CheckPerOblig.Checked)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub EnableDisableAllPOPT(checked As Boolean)

       For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In grdRevenueRecogntion.Rows
         Dim CheckPO As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl("chkPO"), CheckBox)
         CheckPO.Checked = checked
         If CheckPO.Checked Then
            CheckPO.Enabled = False
         End If
         Dim CheckPT As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl("chkPT"), CheckBox)
         CheckPT.Enabled = CheckPO.Checked
       Next

   End Sub
```